# Ruby: unexpected semicolon in block parameters

Tags: ruby

I just started learning Ruby. I typed the [example](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_blocks.html):

```
x = 10
5.times do |y; x|
  x = y
  puts "x inside the block: #{x}"
end
puts "x outside the block: #{x}"
```

And I have an error:

> hello.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting '|'
>   5.times do |y; x|

Explain to me please what does it mean? This code should works, as I understand the chapter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a new 1.9 construct called [block local arguments](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Local+Arguments), you're using 1.8.

---

It also works with lambdas (including stabbed), which is nice:

```
> x = 42
> love_me = ->(y; x) do
*   x = y
*   puts "x inside the block: #{x}"
* end
> 2.times &love_me
x inside the block: 0
x inside the block: 1
> puts "x outside the block: #{x}"
x outside the block: 42
```

Comment: But in the tutorial said: The syntax for a block local variable is simple. Put a semicolon after the normal block parameter list, then list the variable you want as block local variables.

Is it should not works?

Comment: @I159 Great. My question/statement still stands--that's not available in Ruby 1.8. What version of Ruby are you running?

Comment: @I159: actually, just above that specific example, there is this text paragraph: "In Ruby 1.9, blocks introduce their own scope for the block parameters only. This is illustrated by the following example:"

Comment: Yes it is 1.8.7. Thanks a lot.