# sublime text 2 ruby blocks with semicolons error

Tags: ruby, block, sublimetext2

I'm trying out a simple Ruby program to learn about blocks and keep running into a build error when I try use semicolons inside the pipe characters.

If I run the file in Terminal using `ruby name_of_program.rb`, then everything runs fine. It is only when I try to build in Sublime Text that I get the error.

This is the program that errors out in Sublime Text 2 but runs fine outside of it:

```
x = 10

5.times do |x|
  puts "x inside the block: #{x}"
end

puts "x outside the block: #{x}"

x = 10
5.times do |y|
  x = y
  puts "x inside the block: #{x}"
end
puts "x outside the block: #{x}"

x = 10
5.times do |y; x|
  x = y
  puts "x inside the block #{x}"
end
puts "x outside the block #{x}"
```

And the error:

```
block_variables_ex.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting '|'
5.times do |y; x|
```

Any idea as to what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby: unexpected semicolon in block parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963520/ruby-unexpected-semicolon-in-block-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered in "[Ruby: unexpected semicolon in block parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963520/ruby-unexpected-semicolon-in-block-parameters)" in regards to the exact error you are getting. It sounds like Sublime is maybe accessing an older version of Ruby.

Check your path to see if there are two versions of Ruby there and remove all references to Ruby 1.8.

Comment: "remove all references to Ruby 1.8". Let me say that differently: Make sure your path can see only one version of Ruby. If the OP is on a Mac OS machine, Apple includes Ruby 1.8.7 for their use in the default install. Removing that will break functionality that Apple supplies. Instead, use something like RVM or rbenv on Mac OS or Linux, or a similar sandboxing app on Windows, to control the path and manage which Ruby is visible at any particular time.

Comment: Ah I did not know that. Thank you for informing me. Pik would be the choice if you wanted a RVM replacement in Windows.

Comment: Thank you snowe2010 and @the-tin-man! I checked your link then searched for "ruby version sublime text" which led me to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830607/use-default-ruby-version-in-sublime-text-2). I then edited my Ruby.sublime-build file. For anyone else having this issue, this is what my Ruby.sublime-build file now looks like: 

{
 "cmd": ["/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby", "$file"],
 "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
 "selector": "source.ruby"
}

Comment: Glad you could get it figured out!